# Dynamic switch depending on parameters loaded on startup

Tags: c++

How can I create a switch function, that is created during runtime, depending on startup parameters.
My program loads it's configuration from a JSON during startup.
For each entry in that JSON file, there should be a entry in that switch function.

Comment: Your question is about how to create a switch with strings?

Comment: your question is very unclear. Give a "for instance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use map of functors to handle options. But it really depends on your task. Something like this:

```
std::map< std::string, std::function< void( const std::string& ) > > handlers;
// In can be std::variant instead of std::string

handlers[ "key1" ] = []( const std::string& value )
{
    std::cout << "Processing key1 in JSON, value is = " << value ;
};
handlers[ "key2" ] = []( const std::string& value )
{
    std::cout << "Processing key1 in JSON, value is = " << value ;
}; //...

defaultHandler = [](const std::string&)
{
    throw "Not supported param";
};

// Somehow iterate, depends on your json parser
// Can be recursive
for ( const auto& keyVal : json ) 
{
    const auto& key = keyVal.first; // JSON key
    const auto& value= keyVal.second; // JSON value
    const auto itHandler = handlers.find( key ); // Looking for handler
    if ( itHandler != handlers.end() )
    {
        const auto& handler = itHandler.second;
        handler( value ); // Use handler, it's a "content" of your "case" block
    }
    else
        defaultHandler( value );
}
```